# Determine at what points in its domain $f$ is differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have been trying to solve the two problems. Here's what I did:

1) I found the partial derivatives:

(A) $\,f_x = -y\sin(xy)$ and $f_y = -x\sin(xy)$

(B) $\,f_x = ye^{xy} + 2x/(1+x^2+y^2)$ and $f_y = xe^{xy} + 2y/(1+x^2+y^2)$

2) I think that there is a theorem that says that if the partial derivatives of a function are continuous at $(a,b)$ then the function is differentiable at (a,b).

Now I don't know how to show that partial derivatives are continuous.

Is it correct for me to assume that since all the functions are continuous, so their product is also continuous, and hence both partial derivatives are continuous over the domain so the function is differentiable over the domain?

[image]

Comment: If a function is not continuous at some point, it can't be differentiable at this point. The superposition of continuous functions is continuous. Use those facts to solve the exercise

Comment: @Adam that's a very common and fatal misunderstanding that most students in my class made.

Comment: About "part B", why do you think the function isn't continuous at $(x, y)=(0, 0)$? It's continuous

Comment: @Adam my bad I don't know why I forgot that 1 in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Since,

both partial derivatives exist and are continuous for both part(A) and part (B) in their whole domain $R^2$,
so both functions are differentiable at every point in $R^2$.